# iOS Chrome Autofill Not Working On My Website

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, autofill

On my website, **desktop Chrome** autofills my username and password as expected. But when I visit the same page in **iOS Chrome**, autofill exhibits a strange behavior and doesn't autofill the username and password.

By "strange behavior," I mean that I tap on the username field, select my username from the autofill options, and the cursor advances to the next field (password) without populating the username.

I have tested iOS Chrome autofill on several other websites (same iPhone), and they all work fine. Can someone take a look at my login page and tell me if there is something in the HTML/CSS that would prevent iOS Chrome autofill from working? The URL is https://ipanow.com/login-form.

Comment: Did you find a solution fo this? I am having sorta the same issue. Also, is you "SMS" patterened in a certain way?  I have:
12345 is your authentication pin.
@myWebsite.com #12345

but its not working.